# How to have a music player play continuously on a site

Tags: javascript, iframe, audio-player

Hi I just want ask some help, I'm planning to create a site where I can stream live like a online radio. For example like this page https://www.hospitalrecords.com/ the player at the bottom never stops even if you browse the whole site. Is  this javascript? or Iframe? thanks in advance

Arthur

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix the footer of page by following

```
    In CSS:
    .Footer{
        background-color:black;
        height:50px;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
    }
```

and then Add the audio tag on footer...
  In html5(notepad):

```
<body>
    <footer class="Footer">
    <!-- here you can add different audio plugin... but I am using html5 audio for example.. -->
    <audio control auto play loop>// it will loop through the music file
    <source src ="alam.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src ="alam1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
    </footer>
    </body>
```

hope it would be suitable...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will surely try this one.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really familiar with Iframes but this can be done with JavaScript. The general idea would be defining the body that changes as a main div and change the content of that div when a tab is clicked. I am pretty sure there is a more elegant way but you can use
So you will use a lib. of JS called Jquery, I dont know if you are familiar with that.
Your page will consist of a single Html document actually and will have the general layout (looking at the example page you sent)

```
 <html>
  <body>

    <div class="jumbotron"> // This will be div, with a background img
     <ul class="nav"> // This will be you nav bar
        <li id="1"> </li>
        <li id="2>  </li>
     </ul> // For the sake of simplicity I just have 2 tabs 
    </div>
    <div id="mainbody"> ..bunch of initial html</div>
    <div class="footer"> </div> this is the music player
  </body>
</html>
```

For everytab you have in Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(){
           $("#main").html(...."the html of the body you want"...)
    }

$("#2").click(function(){
       $("#main").html(...."the html of the body you want"...)
}
})
```

Since I am guessing your html will get complicated use you can use .load() instead of .html()
Read more about them here 
http://api.jquery.com/html/
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for the comment @sinanspd I'm not really familiar on this part of javascript yet. Can you please explain it more? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Yeah just give me a second